# elastic search join/scripted query ,using output of subquery

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a situation to write search query in elasticsearch having data as follows

```
{id:"p1",person:{name:"name",age:"12"},relatedTO:{id:"p2"}}
{id:"p2",person:{name:"name2",age:"15"},relatedTO:{id:"p3"}}
{id:"p3",person:{name:"name3",age:"17"},relatedTO:{id:"p1"}}
```

scenario:- user's want to search people related to p2,and using each related person find who they are related to

1.first find who are related to p2 answer= p1 
2.Now find people related to p1 answer=p3. *(the requirement as of now is to go only 1-level)*  so no need to find people related to p3.the final result should be p2,p1,p3. 
Normal scenario's we will write a nested sql to get results.How do we achieve this using elastic query language in one-shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one shot you will need to use [Parent-Child-Relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html), but I wouldn't recommand it to you in the first place, because it is not very performant. Btw: also [Grandparents and Grandchildren](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html) are supported.

You could also use [Application Side Joins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html) - meaning you execute several queries, until you get what you want. (Be aware that the first result sets should be very tiny, otherwise this could get costly)

---

**What I would really recommand to you is read this [docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/modeling-your-data.html) and rethink your use case.
In case you want to model relationships like in facebook or google+ I would tell you to look for a NoSQL [Graph Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database).**

---

Note: Ideally in Elasticsearch the data is flat, which means [denormalized](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html).

Comment: after doing some research ,i feel the same that a graph db is needed for complex scenarios like this. Neo4j is one of the product that  i am exploring as of now.I was stuck to solve this in elastic which might no be appropriate.
Multiple queries with include/excludes will solve this but at what cost?,and if scenario changes queries increase.
This activity might take some time but i will update my results in future.Thanks for pointing me in a direction that helps.